# jodit-angular change default target for all links

Tags: angular, hyperlink, default, jodit

I want to set default target=_blank for all links.
I found the applyLink method, but it not work for me...

```
{
  link: {
    openInNewTabCheckbox: false,
  },
  events: {
    applyLink: (jodit, link) => {
      link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    },
  }
}
```

"jodit-angular": "1.11.1"

Reference：https://github.com/xdan/jodit/issues/841